# Mockito only mock part of value and return real value for others

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a unit test with a real object (Data data) and a boolean value (boolean required) as input.

```
mockTest(Data data, boolean required)
```

In my code I have

```
data.getObjectA().getPara1();
```

In other places I also have

```
data.getObjectA().getPara2();
```

And I'm trying to mock the return value of data.getObjectA().getPara1() to the booelan in the input

But below won't work:

```
Mockito.when(data.getObjectA().getPara1()).thenReturn(required);
```

Or

```
Data dataSpy = Mockito.spy(data);
Mockito.when(dataSpy.getObjectA().getPara1()).thenReturn(required);
Mockito.when(dataSpy.getObjectA().getPara2()).thenCallRealMethod();
```

They either throw NullPointerException or Type errors

What is the correct way of mocking/spying it? I need to mock the return of para1 and keep para2 the real value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to override ObjectA's behavior, then the instance that `data` returns needs to be a mock or spy. Fundamentally you have three choices:

#### Use a spy

As in [Dawood's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73954015/1426891):

```java
Data dataMock = Mockito.mock(Data.class);
ClassA objectASpy = Mockito.spy(objectA);
when(dataMock.getObjectA()).thenReturn(objectASpy);
when(objectASpy.getPara1()).thenReturn(required);    // note 1
```

If you want `getPara1()` to return the same result for any *internal* calls within `objectASpy`, this is the way to go.

#### Use [delegatesTo](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/AdditionalAnswers.html#delegatesTo(java.lang.Object))

This opts into a delegation-based behavior for Mockito, rather than overriding as it usually does.

```java
Data dataMock = Mockito.mock(Data.class);
ClassA objectAMock = Mockito.mock(ObjectA.class, delegatesTo(objectA));
when(dataMock.getObjectA()).thenReturn(objectAMock);
when(objectASpy.getPara1()).thenReturn(required);    // note 1
```

If you only want `getPara1()` to return `required` on the *outside* calls, but have `objectASpy` return its original value for its internal calls, you could use this technique.

#### Use [deep stubbing](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html)

Mockito does have a feature that would allow for your current syntax:

```java
Mockito.when(dataSpy.getObjectA().getPara1()).thenReturn(required);
Mockito.when(dataSpy.getObjectA().getPara2()).thenCallRealMethod();
```

This feature is called *returning deep stubs*, and is best for when an object like `dataSpy` here represents a tree of very straightforward objects. That said, heed its warning:

> **WARNING:** This feature should rarely be required for regular clean code! Leave it for legacy code. Mocking a mock to return a mock, to return a mock, (...), to return something meaningful hints at violation of Law of Demeter or mocking a value object (a well known anti-pattern).

#### Note 1

The line `when(objectASpy.getPara1()).thenReturn(required);` will actually call `objectASpy.getPara1()`. This might be fine as long as the object doesn't throw an exception and doesn't have side effects, but you can avoid that behavior with `doVerb` syntax so Mockito can see ahead of the call that you're starting to stub.

Note that unlike `when().thenReturn()` syntax, the `when` below only contains the mock instead of the full mock method call.

```java
doReturn(required).when(objectASpy).getPara1();
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is to stub the call to `getObjectA()` separately, to return another mock or spy, where you stub `getPara1()` and/or `getPara2()`.  So it might look something like this.

```
Data dataMock = Mockito.mock(Data.class);
ClassA objectASpy = Mockito.spy(objectA);
when(dataMock.getObjectA()).thenReturn(objectASpy);
when(objectASpy.getPara1()).thenReturn(required);
```

I also recommend using annotations for your mocking and spying.  So you might have field declarations like

```
@Mock
private Data dataMock;

@Spy
private ClassA objectASpy;
```

outside of the test method itself.